# Regex doesn't work for same data occasionally

Tags: c#, regex

I have following regex:

```
<div[^>]*>(?<Value>[^<]*(?:(?!</div)<[^<]*)*)[</div>]*
```

This regex works perfectly almost all the times for same set of data, but sometimes it doesn't.

I have following piece of code:

```
matchValue = oMatch.Groups["Value"].Value.ToLower();
if ((Regex.Match(matchValue, @"(effective\s*date)").Value).Equals("effective date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true || (Regex.Match(matchValue, @"(eff\s*date)").Value).Equals("eff date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
{
    headings = matchValue;
    headingsData = oMatch.NextMatch().Value;
}
```

Also I am using Multiline as RegexOptions.

I am using the above code with Threading concept

Now I get correct value in "headings" and "headingsData" almost every time, but sometimes I get correct value in headings but the the value for "headingsData" changes.

Can anyone tell me the reason for such an situation?

Comment: You'll have to show us your threading code for us to be of any use. By the sounds of it.. your threads are racing..

Comment: And while you are at it, add two or three paragraphs of explanation why you are using regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: That too.. what @Tomalak said.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");

// All divs that does not contain other divs
string xpath = "//div[not(.//div)]";

bool previousWasHeading = false;
foreach(HtmlNode div in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath))
{
    if (previousWasHeading)
    {
        // Previous <div> was the heading, this one is the heading data.
        headingsData = div.Text;
        previousWasHeading = false;
        break; // Stop after first heading/headingData
    }
    else if (div.InnerText.Contains("effective date") || div.InnerText.Contains("eff date"))
    {
        // This this <div> is the heading.
        heading = div.Text;
        previousWasHeading = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this could be expressed as a one-liner `//div[not(.//div)][preceding::div[not(.//div)][1][contains(., 'effective date') or contains(., 'eff date')]]` - but then again you'd have to see the input document.